# Performance on iPad file writes

Tags: ios, ipad

We have a POS apartment leasing iPad app that is used to collect a lot of data about a user and their interests (with their knowledge of course).

We use RestKit to sync CoreData with the server, which is totally sweet.

What I'm trying to do is have a backup system so if Core Data chokes, and my recorded stack trace doesn't contain the data I need, I still have the data saved somehow. I never want to lose data.

So what I'm doing here is writing the user data to a file on disk in addition to CoreData, and wipe the file when the session ends if nothing went wrong. If something does go wrong, it is sent along with the stack trace to HockeyApp when the app launches again.

So my question is one of performance. How often can I write to this text file before it affects performance? There are a bunch of screens in this app that they can page through as they enter information. They could page pretty quickly, and I don't want it to cause delays. Is that something I should consider or am I way off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, you must quantify the size and complexity of a write operation.

Anyways, what's stopping you from using C libraries, or more specifically the more typical C approach? Here's the difference in approaches you often see:

- C: For each change, append some bytes to the file
- ObjC: For each change (set), create a property list or archive of all the stuff. Write said property list in its entirety to disk.

The incremental approach is also possible using lower level CF/NS IO types. Notably:

- `NSFileHandle`
- `NSOutputStream`
- `CFWriteStream`

These types are capable of sync and async writes.

At any rate - if you have a lot of data to write and reformat to a property list upon each transaction, then you should consider incremental writes instead.

Comment: That would be because I don't really know C. :) But incremental sounds like a good idea. If they can pick a couple values in a row (pick table) would I still need to thread those so they don't slow it down, per Alex's answer, or would I be ok. These are small values like "Washer" "Fireplace", etc. So small amount of bytes.

Comment: @Bob try `NSFileHandle` if you need incremental writes. it's the higher level async objc incremental writer. (answer expanded)

Answer (score 1):

You can test things to determine performance, but above all else, your file writes and other non-UI work can be threaded (see [`NSThread`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsthread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [`NSOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) references). Putting this work into background threads helps ensure that your app's interface, which runs on the main thread, should not *appear* to slow down.